# Need to import mssql backup file(.bak file) into postgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, database-design

Need to import MSSQL backup file(.bak file) into postgres directly and I don't have MSSQL installed and I cannot install it in my machine, Is there any way which I can directly import MSSQL bak file to postgres local db

Thank you in Advance!!

Comment: *"Need to import MySQL backup file(.bak file)"* MySQL doesn't use Bak Files, that's a SQL Server thing. And no, Bak files are propriety to SQL Server; you can't restore one to a different RDBMS.

Comment: Assuming it is a SQL Server `bak` file, you can install SQL Server LocalDB very quickly, and it will take a database up to 10GB. Then use some kind of ETL wizard to transfer to Postgres

Comment: Either the question is wrong formulated, or this question has nothing to do with `sql-server` Please adjust your question or your tags

Comment: I am Sorry, Corrected my question, its MSSQL. Thanks for your quick replies! Will take approvals to install MSSQL and migrate it using ETl.

Comment: They are different products. This is like trying to restore a mac from a linux backup.